# CSS - Change position of buttons on bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have problem with positioning of buttons on bootstrap navbar. They are not aligned with website title and they are too close together. The code looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="new-point"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="feature-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>&nbsp;</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mleontenko/poqbkxrt/

I need to align buttons to website name and add a little bit of space between the two buttons. CSS trick that solves this would be appreciated.

Comment: That fiddle has no css applied to it, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/poqbkxrt/1/

```css
li {
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="new-point"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;</button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="feature-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>&nbsp;</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

By default the `.nav` on the `.navbar` component relies on hyperlinks for its navigation.  Those hyperlinks have `padding` defined by Bootstrap's CSS to properly space each item in relation to the `.navbar-brand`.

Since you are using `<button>` elements you will need to add your own CSS, such as the following:

```
.navbar-nav .btn {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for you !!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="new-point"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="feature-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>&nbsp;</button></li>
      </ul>

      </div>
     </div>
    </nav>
```

HAPPY TO HELP !!